# How can I delete objects through a shared pointer to a tuple

Tags: c++, c++11

We have a data structure of below format:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Aclass>, std::shared_ptr<BClass>>>;

auto ret = method();
```

One of the method returns data type of above mentioned type - how can I delete Aclass and Bclass or rather how can access each pointer of the class and delete them explicitly?

Comment: Yes we need to explicitly delete them - can you please provide how can I access and delete them locally - they are defined in a header file - please provide some code references

Comment: The *point* of a `shared_ptr` is that no single place gets to decide "This object dies now". If you want that control, use `unique_ptr`

Comment: Explicitly deleting objects pointed at by shared_ptr results with dangling pointer in shared_ptr that will be deleted again (undefined behavior) when shared count reaches zero.  Basically you are asking how to implement undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks I understand your point - so how can I access each element of the tuple using its shared pointer

Comment: Why do you think that you need to explicitly delete these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::get<0>(*ret).reset();` and `std::get<1>(*ret).reset();` will do the trick.

`std::get` is used to get an element from a tuple: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get and `reset` decrements the reference counter of the object owned by the pointer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset eventually destroying.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `reset` on whichever shared pointer you want to delete. Note that the underlying object will not be deleted immediately unless the reference count reaches 0.
For example:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Aclass>, std::shared_ptr<BClass>>> ret = method();
// delete AClass
std::get<0>(*ret).reset()
// delete BClass
std::get<1>(*ret).reset()
// delete the whole tuple including AClass and BClass if they haven't already been reset.
ret.reset();
```